# Matching URLs found in Tweets

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm involved in doing a project which requires removal of URLs

Is there a good regex for matching any URL in Ruby 1.8.7 ?

PS - I have one

```
/(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’])\/* )/x
```

The regex is at http://www.rubular.com/r/UFDveGLNGt with a few example strings
How do i match websites like fb.me or goo.gl or google.com ?

Comment: You have a non-escaped forward slash at the end. The end should be: `)\/))/`

Comment: @enrico.bacis


check this [Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/dYTJUJTETH) 
tried it before - some really complex error

Comment: @enrico.bacis
I fixed it [Rubular Link]http://www.rubular.com/r/OGt43uxWfw . But still not matching all types of URLs I wish to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
require 'uri'
URI.regexp
```

This evaluates to:

```
/
    ([a-zA-Z][\-+.a-zA-Z\d]*):                           (?# 1: scheme)
    (?:
       ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)                    (?# 2: opaque)
    |
       (?:(?:
         \/\/(?:
             (?:(?:((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)@)?        (?# 3: userinfo)
               (?:((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\]))(?::(\d*))?))? (?# 4: host, 5: port)
           |
             ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)                 (?# 6: registry)
           )
         |
         (?!\/\/))                           (?# XXX: '\/\/' is the mark for hostport)
         (\/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:\/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?                    (?# 7: path)
       )(?:\?((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?                 (?# 8: query)
    )
    (?:\#((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?                  (?# 9: fragment)
  /x
```

This will probably be better than anything we can come up here *(otherwise consider submitting it to `ruby`)*.

Comment: it doesnt match stuff like pic.twitter.com/* - they are really common twitter

Comment: Got a good regex - [Link](http://www.rubular.com/r/UFDveGLNGt)
But not matching website links like google.com or fb.me or 9gag.tv